# Check if float is equal to another X number after dot in C

Tags: c, precision

i want to check if a float is equal to another but only X number after the dot.
For X = 3:
0.1234 == 0.1235

```
if (float1.X == float2.X)
      do something
else
      do something
```

Comment: Are you trying to figure out whether `float1` and `float2` are the same or different, to a significance of three places past the decimal?  If so, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70754073/check-if-float-is-equal-to-another-x-number-after-dot-in-c/70757254#70757254).

Comment: For the most part, you should not be attempting to compare floating-point numbers to a certain number of digits. There are only limited circumstances in which this is a correct solution to some problem. In general, it cannot compensate for rounding errors introduced by prior floating-point calculations. You should explain the context of what you are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floating point calculations are imprecise may lead to surprising rounding errors: Therefore I'll recommend that you avoid floating point calculations before comparing the fractional part.
Instead use `sprintf` to print the values to strings. Then compare the number of decimals you want in the two stings. Make sure to use a sufficiently large width specifier to avoid unexpected roundings. For IEEE 754 32 bit floats the maximum number of decimals will be a little less than 150.

Start with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    float f1 = 1.23456;
    float f2 = 1.23457;
    char str_f1[512];
    char str_f2[512];
    sprintf(str_f1, "%.160f", f1);
    printf("%s\n", str_f1);
    sprintf(str_f2, "%.160f", f2);
    printf("%s\n", str_f2);

    // Add code for string compare using X decimals
    
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1.234560012817382812500000000000000000000000000000000000000000...
1.234570026397705078125000000000000000000000000000000000000000...
```

So `str_f1` and `str_f2` are now two simple strings so you it's easy to compare them with exactly the number of decimals that you want.

Comment: `%.60f` is a fair shot at super-wide precession needs of a `float`.  Note that the typical smallest `float` needs about 150 places for _exact_ decimal representation.  IAC, `sprintf()` cannot  reliable handle such, but an upper bound for what could be needed.  I suspect this `sprint()` approach is likely the one a prof may be looking for, yet in the extremes cases (something I doubt OP needs), it is not sufficient.

Comment: Hmmm, DV here unwarranted as it is a workable approach given some limitations.  Have an UV.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Thanks for your input. I'm kind of interested in cases where `sprintf` doesn't print the correct, exact value even if the width specifier is sufficient.

Comment: @4386427 I'm not precisely sure which case(s) chux might have been referring to, but it turns out that correctly converting a floating-point number to a decimal string representation is a surprisingly hard problem.  Proper algorithms are known (cf. "dragon4", "grisu", and "ryu"), and good C libraries use them when implementing `%f` and `%e` for `printf` and `sprintf`, but poor libraries do not, and will display various anomalies.

Comment: 4386427, @SteveSummit well said it.  Further, C does not specify the quality of `sprintf()`, yet it is reasonable to assume the first N _significant_ decimal digits are correct.  N >= `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG` (17) is needed for `double` which is what `"%f"` gets, to make round-tripping successful.  IEEE-754 compliance requires, from my memory,  N >= 20 (17 + 3).  Yet for 2 `float`s, after `FLT_DECIMAL_DIG` (9) _significant_ digits, the distinctiveness is fully discernable, I revise my estimated precision needs down to 45 for `FLT_MIN` "'0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000117549435". So `"% .45f"`

Comment: 4386427, Recommend using `modff()` on `f1,f2` as that 1) makes the max buffer needs smaller and 2) makes comparing the strings simpler.

Comment: With respect to the question of "cases where `sprintf` doesn't print the correct, exact value", I'm reminded of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70057191).  (See especially Eric Postpischil's comment.)

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Ì think `%.45f` will too little. See https://ideone.com/WYiuCF

Comment: @4386427 But the goal is to compare 2 `float`s, not simply print the `float`.  I still assert `printf("% .45f\n", FLT_TRUE_MIN);` is enough for the compare.  Actually I'd go for `printf("% .*f\n", FLT_MANT_DIG - FLT_MIN_EXP, FLT_TRUE_MIN);` for portability.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica The idea is to print to strings and then do the compare on strings. Printing only 45 decimals gives to few characters in the string: https://ideone.com/9ogmyc

Comment: @4386427 Sample code did not do any compare.  Yet if it did, "0.00...0011754944" vs. "0.00...0000000001" would compare the same  even with more digits.  Same as with any 2 `float`s, even `FLT_TRUE_MIN` and `FLT_TRUE_MIN * 2`.

Comment: Re “Any calculation that you do on the two variables may change the fractional value”: No, a number of floating-point operations are known to be exact. These include multiplying and dividing by a power of the floating-point base, within bounds, taking a symmetric remainder (as in `remainder`), separating integer and fraction parts (as in `modf`), and subtracting two numbers of the same sign whose magnitudes differ by a factor of at most two.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I'm not sure if the word "float" in the question title means: "Data type `float`" or: "Floating point number", which may correspond to the data type `double`...

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly what you asked, but if you're trying to determine whether `float1` and `float2` are approximately equal, to within X significant digits, the usual way to do it is to subtract the two numbers, and see if the difference is less than a threshold.  (And, of course, you have to take the absolute value into account.)  So, for three significant digits, something like this:

```
if(fabs(float1 - float2) < 0.001)
    do something;
else
    do something else;
```

Or, to do it with a variable `X`:

```
if(fabs(float1 - float2) < pow(10, -X))
    do something;
else
    do something else;
```

Comment: This is likely close to what OP really needs.  Yet unclear why use `double` functions and constants instead of `float` ones.

Comment: That won't work: If `X` is 1, `123 == 123.09` shall be true (although `123 - 123.09` is `0.09`) but `123 == 122.99999` shall be false (although `123 - 122.99999` = `0.0001`).

Comment: @MartinRosenau Answer updated.  This isn't what the OP explicitly asked for, but I suspect it might be what they actually need.  (What the OP explicitly asked for has no practical value that I can see, while of course an 'approximately equal' comparison is a common need.)